# i want the cooment in sert in the upper not in the lowest

Tags: php

now i searched for comments system
one of my friends suggest to me
this 
Advanced PHP Comments System With jQuery
and i download from his tutorial like
Jooria-Comments-0.02.zip [5.17 KB]
http://www.jooria.      com/downloads/442/Jooria-Comments-0.02.zip

its really nice
but the only disadvantage is it add the insertedd comment
in the bottom of the old comments

i want it add the new one in the top on old comments

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort commends descending within query fetching the comments something like below:

```
 select * from comments order by id desc
```

Comment: this will arrange the old comments
but i want the new one inserting in the top
please download the script and test it you will understand

Comment: Sounds like you need to modify the javascript. Look for where it `append`'s the comment and change it to `prepend` or where it's calling `after` and go from there. The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation) will help.

Comment: @moustafa: that query will bring new records on top.

Comment: Possibly the javascript it just adding it to the end of the list when it gets posted though.